# Why can't i adjust the width of <td>?

Tags: html, vue.js, html-table

I used a normal HTML table in Vue for some reason,

```
<div class="mytable" style="overflow-x:auto">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th v-for="header in headers">{{header}}</th>
            <tr>
        <thead>
        <tbody>
               <tr v-for="item in items">
                   <td>
                       {{item}}
                   </td>
               </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Now I set a `overflow-x:auto` because the result can be very long, the rendering works fine and all. However, when I tried to adjust the width of a column, nothings happens. I tried `<td width="300">`, I also tried `<td style="width:300px">`. I even tried editing the width in Google chrome console debugger, but still nothing happens.

Here's a simple image of the current table : [image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `table-layout: fixed` when you want the individual table cells to respect pre-defined CSS widths:

```
.mytable {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Comment: I've also tried this one, still no luck. Or maybe it wont change unless I set the width of the th first? does it work that way? or will the <th> automatically adjusts based on <td>'s width?